# Error when install 2nd gen package flexipage to scratch org

Tags: managed-package, flexipages, second-generation-packaging, issue

I've got an error when deploying 2nd gen package to scratch org

> (Flexi_Page) Data Not Available
> The data you were trying to access could not be found. It may be due to another user deleting the data or a system error. If you know the data is not deleted but cannot access it, please look at our <a href="{0}" title="support{1}" support</a> page.

When I deployed this package version to sandbox I did not receive any errors. Could someone explain what should be done?

Comment: Does your scratch org have a namespace assigned, and is it the same as the package?

Comment: @Phil W -i guess yes, because I've created this scratch from Dev hub, where namespace was registered. But let me create the new one

Comment: The namespace is specified in the sfdx-project.json or scratch def, can't remember which, not the dev hub.

Comment: Yeah, I used this link https://sfdx-isv.github.io/sfdx-workshop/sfdx-managed-packages/create-a-namespaced-scratch-org/

Comment: Well, if the scratch org has the package's namespace and you try to install the package rather than deploy the package's metadata to it, stuff will go wrong. You either have the namespace on the org and deploy, or you have no namespace on the org (or some other namespace) and install.

Comment: @Phil W - After many attempts of deploying I've noticed that flexipage overrides profile settings but I did not have this profile in my scratch org.

`<profileActionOverrides><actionName>Tab</actionName><content>HomePage</content><formFactor>Large</formFactor><pageOrSobjectType>standard-home</pageOrSobjectType><type>Flexipage</type><profile>Custom Profile Name</profile></profileActionOverrides>`

So I cloned existing profile with brand new name (**Custom Profile Name**) and package installed successfully!

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You should add the detail as an answer...

Answer (score 0):

After many attempts of deploying I've noticed that flexipage overrides profile settings but I did not have this profile in my scratch org.

```
<profileActionOverrides>
    <actionName>Tab</actionName>
    <content>flexipage_api_name</content>
    <formFactor>Large</formFactor>
    <pageOrSobjectType>standard-home</pageOrSobjectType>
    <type>Flexipage</type>
    <profile>Custom Profile Name</profile>
</profileActionOverrides>
```

So I've cloned existing profile with brand new name (Custom Profile Name) and package installed successfully! Thanks for your help, @Phil W!